# Unclear of details of limit for a Taylor expansion of moment generating function - test this Wed!

Tags: central-limit-theorem

I keep coming across these limits - the context is moment generating functions and the Central Limit Theorem, but I'm guessing it's a more general question - here is one example (from the proof for the weak law of large numbers):

$$(1 -  \frac{t^2}{2n} + o(\frac{t^2}{2n}))^n \rightarrow  e^\frac{-t^2}{2} \\ \\
as \\ {n \rightarrow \infty}$$

I have not been able to find instructions that explain a few details which is keeping me from feeling fully comfortable with it (and it's almost guaranteed to show up in some form on the test).

My questions are

1. What exactly is the o term? I understand it's some kind of remainder term when doing a Taylor expansion, but what rules does it follow? I've seen examples where t is moved outside of the o term in calculations. I've also seen the following (where the the t term doesn't even appear in the o term)

$$(1 + \frac{t^2}{6n} + o(\frac{1}{n}))^n \rightarrow  e^\frac{t^2}{6} \\ \\
as \\ {n \rightarrow \infty}$$

Can the Taylor expansion be written out as an arbitrary number of terms as long as you add the appropriate o term? That's the impression I'm getting (i.e. I could continue up to t^3, t^4 etc I just have to modify the o term).

2. If the n was not in the denominator, would it still converge. i.e.

$$ ?? (1 -  \frac{t^2}{2} + o(\frac{t^2}{2}))^n \rightarrow  e^\frac{-t^2}{2} ?? \\ \\
as \\ {n \rightarrow \infty}$$

3. In the examples I've seen where this limit is used, it always only involves one term. I.e. either the first t term is removed (due to having a 0 product, as in the examples above), or only the first term is expanded like this:

$$(1 +  \frac{ta}{n} + o(\frac{t}{n}))^n \rightarrow  e^{ta} \\ \\
as \\ {n \rightarrow \infty}$$

What would happen if both the t and t^2 where included  - would it still converge the same (or does it specifically need to be 1 + a single t term + the oterm)? i.e. something like:

$$??(1 +  \frac{ta}{n} +  \frac{(ta)^2}{2n} + o(\frac{t}{n}))^n \rightarrow  e^{ta}?? \\ \\
as \\ {n \rightarrow \infty}$$

I appreciate any help, I just can't seem to figure these details out and they are throwing a wrench in my apparatus...thanks!!

Comment: Look up "little-oh notation"